# Optimize query to count total from two different column and different rows of one table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Table **accounts**

```
Id    price     currency      date 
1      10        USD         2013-01-12  
2      200       GBP         2013-01-13 
3      30        GBP         2013-01-14 
4      85        USD         2013-01-20 
5      80        GBP         2013-01-25 
6     120        GBP         2013-01-30 
7     180        GBP         2013-01-31 
8     100        GBP         2013-02-04
```

I want to count it as from one month like this:

```
Total:  USD     95  
Total:  GBP     610
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use `GROUP BY` and an *aggregate function* `SUM()` to calculate its total.

```
SELECT  currency, SUM(price) totalPrice
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY currency
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7034/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*by month*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7034/4)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*by month and year*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7034/5)